# Loading layer from SpatiaLite database, using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, geometry, spatialite

I'm new to SpatiaLite and PyQGIS.

I would like to upload a layer from SpatiaLite database. To do this, I tried with this code:

```
database = r"C:\sqlite\db.sqlite"
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setDatabase(database)
schema = ''
table = 'table_name'
geom_column = 'point'
uri.setDataSource(schema, table, geom_column)
display_name = 'table_name'
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), display_name, 'spatialite')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

But this doesn't work, the program says:

> Unavailable layer! Layer datasource could not be found

I think the problem may be the value of "geom_column".
The table has a column called "the_geo", where the row values are POINT(x_value, y_value).

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you change `geom_column = 'point'` with `geom_column = 'the_geo'` ?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work

Comment: Is the path to the file actually correct?

Answer (score -2):

```
int result;
    QString sql = QStringLiteral("select table_name, type, label_field from kt_master");
    sqlite3_statement_unique_ptr preparedStatement = mDatabase.prepare(sql, result);

QMap<QString, QList<QString>> masterInfo;
masterInfo.clear();

while (preparedStatement.step() == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    QgsDataSourceUri uri = QgsDataSourceUri();
    uri.setDatabase(mFilePath);
    uri.setDataSource("", preparedStatement.columnAsText(0), "geom");
```